# OCaml - Timestamp field anomaly with ocaml-mysql

Tags: mysql, ocaml

I'm having issues executing the following MySQL statement with the ocaml-mysql (latest version) library:

```
  let dump_to_db text =
      let insert = P.create db (s "INSERT INTO Temperature VALUES (?,?,?,?)") in
        ignore (P.execute insert [| "NULL"; "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; text ; "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" |])
```

My problem is that the timestamp field is not set correctly. Apparently, whatever I write into the last field (might it be "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" or simply "NULL"), I'm not able to get the proper outcome.

What happens is that the query get executed and what I see inside the table is a NULL-filled Timestamp field (even tho I have no idea how it can be possible because is defined as a NOT NULL column).

My table structure follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Temperature` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IP` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Value` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Prepared.execute` takes array with values not arbitrary expressions (function calls). String value "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" gets converted into timestamp and as it is not recognized as valid number is turned into zero.
Pass `NULL` properly and it will be default initialized according to `CREATE TABLE` :
`P.execute_null insert [| None; Some "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; Some text ; None |]`